# Как записать одну строку в пять переменных в С?

Tags: c

Как записать одну строку в пять переменных в С?

Цель такая: юзер вводит пять чисел через пробел. они могут быть 1 значными 2 значными итд. Вопрос: как записать эти пять чисел не в одну переменную `char`, а в пять переменных (пять массивов). Пример: юзер ввел

> 1 423 3 53 6

Переменная *а=1*, *б=423*, *в=3*, *г=53*, *д=6*, при этом чтобы в каждом элементе массива содержалось одно число: *б[0]=4*, *б[1]=2*

Пишу на С, программа без интерфейса (выглядит как командная строка).

Вот код:

```
int i, j, a1,a2,a3,a4;

char inp[50], a1[5],a2[5],a3[5],a4[5],a5[5];
scanf("%s", &inp);
for(i=0; inp[i]!=" ";i++){
    a1[i]=inp[i];
}
for(i=i; inp[i]!=" ";i++){
    j=0;
    a2[j]=inp[i];
    j++;
}
for(i=i; inp[i]!=" ";i++){
    j=0;
    a3[i]=inp[i];
    j++;
}
for(i=i; inp[i]!=" ";i++){
    j=0;
    a4[i]=inp[i];
    j++;
}
for(i=i; inp[i]!=" ";i++){
    j=0;
    a5[i]=inp[i];
    j++;
}
```

Comment: И что вы сами написали?

Comment: @LEQADA, думаю сначала считывать строку целиком, потом познаково ее проверять - проверяемый знак пробел или нет, если пробел, то переходить к записи в след. переменную, если нет, то продолжить запись в эту же

Comment: @LEQADA, добавил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Эм.. В этом коде неправильно всё что только можно... Я даже не уверен, компилируется ли он, но если да, то все условия for'ов ложны. Учись отличать строки от символов.

Comment: А ещё, у тебя заголовок вопроса и сам вопрос противоположны по смыслу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать пять раз `scanf("%d",<переменна>);`. Если хотим считать число, то так

```
int result[5];
for(int i = 0;i<5;++i)
    scanf("%d", &result[i]);
```

Если хотим считать как строку, то так

```
char result[5][5];
for(int i = 0;i<5;++i)
    scanf("%s", result[i]);
```

Дополню свой ответ

```
const int COUNT_OF_VALUES = 5;

char inp[50], values[COUNT_OF_VALUES][5];

const char separator[]=" "; //Символы-разделители строки
char *pNumber = NULL; //Указатель для функции strtok

gets(inp);  //считает строку до символа новой строки

pNumber=strtok(inp,separtor); 

int i = 0;
while(pNumber)
{
    strcpy(values[i],pNumber);
    i++;
    pNumber=strtok(0,separator);    
}
```

Comment: нужно чтобы ввод 5 переменных происходил через пробелы

Comment: @Nik, он, по-моему, будет каждое число считывать до пробела

Comment: @Nik, да, `scanf` читает до первого разделителя, коим может выступать и пробел.

Comment: @Nik, я дополнил свой ответ. Возможно, второй способ Вам поможет больше.